# Podcast #3: iMac upgrades, Spotlight tips, Tiny Wings

Tags: discussion, podcast-episode

This is the third episode of the Ask Different Podcast, an unofficial podcast created by members of the Ask Different community about Apple and related technologies.

Your hosts this week are [Kyle Cronin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin), [Jason Salaz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1346/vxjasonxv), and [Nathan Greenstein](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2220/nathan).

- Kyle begins with some news about this podcast: We’ve launched! We want to thank everyone that has sent us feedback, we appreciate it. Also, we’re now featured on the [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/category/podcasts/askdifferent/).
- Nathan describes Stack Exchange’s [recent efforts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) to boost voting on questions, especially relative to answers. Verdict: if you see a great question on Ask Different, vote it up!
- Jason discusses LastPass’ recent [possible security breach](http://blog.lastpass.com/2011/05/lastpass-security-notification.html), what this means, how LastPass is responding, and what users of the service should do as a result. Jason also brings us a correction to a previous episode regarding which features are available in the free vs paid plans.
- Nathan updates us with [hard data](http://news.consumerreports.org/electronics/2011/05/apples-white-iphone-is-not-thicker-than-black-version.html) about the white iPhone 4’s alleged width gain, and discusses whether or not the color of the  actually makes a difference.
- Kyle delivers an iPhone tracking update: [Official iOS update released](http://feeds.arstechnica.com/~r/arstechnica/index/~3/oIa9Cxxbo7E/ios-433-is-out-with-location-tracking-fixes-for-iphone-ipad.ars). What it changes, and how it helps you stay more secure. Jason discusses Apple’s impressive response to the tracking issue.
- We discuss the fact that, while Android phones are more popular than the iPhone, the iPad is much more popular than the slew of available Android tablets. Do Android and iOS tablet customers expect different things from their tablets? Are the iPad’s main advantages timing and price?
- Nathan takes us through the [recent upgrades](http://www.macworld.com/article/159611/2011/05/thunderbolt_imacs.html) to the iMac line, we discuss if it’s worth getting the 21-inch model, and whether or not the two Thunderbolt ports on the 27-inch model eliminate most of the need for a Mac Pro.
- Kyle compares how (relatively) easy it is to [service the newer iMacs](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/iMac-Intel-27-Inch-Hard-Drive-Replacement/1634/1) compared with the older [iMac G3](http://www.flickr.com/photos/magistermgp/sets/72157610300582836/) and [iMac G4](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/systems/iMac_g4/imacg4_takeapart.html).
- We share some tips on how to get Spotlight to work for you, including excluding certain directories and [search paramaters](http://viewer.zoho.com/api/urlview.do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhints.macworld.com%2Fdlfiles%2Fspotlight_cmds.pdf) (pdf) based on the file metadata.
- Our Question of the Week was asked by [Carlos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6212/carlos): [Snow Leopard Server as main (everyday) OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13383/snow-leopard-server-as-main-everyday-os), and we discuss whether it’s a good idea to run desktop apps on a server.
- Our App of the Week is [Tiny Wings](http://www.andreasilliger.com/), a game for iPhone and iPad where you play as a bird and try to fly as far as you can before the sun sets. Tiny Wings is available on the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tiny-wings/id417817520?mt=8&affId=1936001&ign-mpt=uo%3D4).

This episode was recorded on Saturday, May 7th. You can subscribe to this podcast via [RSS](http://feeds.feedburner.com/AskDifferentPodcast) or [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/id435683997). If you have any feedback or questions you’d like for us to answer on air, leave a comment on this post or e-mail us at podcast@askdifferent.net.

[Download](http://media.podcast.askdifferent.net/3.mp3)

Comment: yay another episode! btw, shouldn't it say "Podcast #3" instead of "Podcast #2" on the Superuser blog?

Comment: @Jin The posts on the Super User Blog are a bit delayed. I've queued up a new post for this episode, but it's up to the people that are running the blog when they'll publish it. Also, we'd love to hear from you if you have any feedback or suggestions about the podcast.

Comment: Invite me! I want to be as famous as Kyle!  J/K :)

Comment: @Martín As this is supposed to be a podcast about the Ask Different community, I'd very much like your input - what we're doing right, suggestions for improvement, recommendations for app of the week/question of the week, maybe even a few questions we could answer 'on air'. We do definitely plan on getting guests on in the near future, but we need to sort out a few things on the production end first (it's still very chaotic and unorganized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is here to be accepted only so that Community ♦ doesn't bump it.